# Show not-inherited methods in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete

In Android Studio on Windows, with <kbd>CTRL-SPACE</kbd> when the cursor is after an object I can see all the methods exposed by that object's class, that I can use; but often they are dozens, if not even hundreds, most of which are irrelevant because inherited from generic parent classes.
I would like to have a help popup that filters for me only methods (or at least sorts them) that exist right in that class and not in all parents, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the base Android Studio IDE (or any Jetbrains based IDE).

There is a code-completion settings section under *Preferences >Editor>General>CodeCompletion* but it is pretty basic and you can do no such customization there.

It should however be possible with a plugin, as discussed [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206584119-Creating-a-custom-autocomplete).

Comment: Every time IntelliJ surprises me for how is powerful, and at the same time lacks of basic functions...

Comment: As you know is there at least a way to clearly display which is the class every single method is inherited from?

Comment: @Beppi's what 1 person finds essential, another person would never think of using :) they cannot add endless functionality. I have no answer to the question in the comment, sorry

Comment: of course :-) Anyway I find pretty frustrating to dig into hundreds of methods to just discover that was called "PutXY" instead of "AddXY" :-)

Comment: @Beppi you can always open the source for the class, or check the documentation. Then it's easy to separate class methods vs inherited methods

Comment: Yes, indeed. Currently I Ctrl-B on the class name to open the source and then go into the Structure panel to understand what's happening, I hoped that there was a faster way :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to the override methods just press CTRL+O it will show you the essential methods needed. @Beppi's there is a way to know that just right click the class you would like to know where it is. Then just press GoToDeclaration